# Correct Condition For Window.External.Notify is Defined

Tags: javascript, windows-phone, notify, hybrid, window.external

I'm developing hybrid application that require to call window.external.notify in javascript but this js code should run in browser also. So we have to have a condition for detecting is window.external.notify is defined or undefined. So we use that code but in runtime window.external.notify shows its value is like that {...} (but can't open). Are there any way to handle it?

```
if(window.external !== undefined && window.external.notify !== undefined)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if (typeof (window.external) !== 'undefined' && ('notify' in window.external)) {
....
}
```

For reasons only known to Microsoft, `window.external.notify` is `undefined` even though you can make calls to it without any issues.